# sQL query performance issue ( many to many relationship tables)

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many, query-performance

I have a object file to source file relationship as below

```
--
OBJECT_FILE: F:/XX/YY/ZZ/OperatingSystem.o  e4cd09e5fc1c74ec6a2e24c361f7103d3a4036a2    5
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/OperatingSystem.cpp ba06447d296ceae294962bbf130406052ebb9d7c    2
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/OperatingSystem.hpp     272b23c2590b2f2e908b9f7e148a1dfcb61183d8    4
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/Types.h     2375eeec03d837b351a0c105e663dcea6aee434d    3
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/time.h      f7a9165daf21d6f200ad656fbace652fcde11c4b    3
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/cdefs.h     f0704e779b9252398f7859a05cc65bbd563cdd0e    3
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/cdefs_elf.h     63e208b3b175f84e32918d08096693688d860869    3
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/time.h      f4eaf411f6b1a8817f3baed1bfbacd4ea2f51b9f    3
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/cdefs.h     f0704e779b9252398f7859a05cc65bbd563cdd0e    3
OBJECT_FILE: F:/XX/YY/ZZ/CIpInterface.o e4cd09e5fc1c74ec6a2e24c361f7103d3a4036a2    5
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/CIpInterface.cpp    ba06447d296ceae294962bbf130406052ebb9d7c    2
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/OperatingSystem.hpp     272b23c2590b2f2e908b9f7e148a1dfcb61183d8    4
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/Types.h     2375eeec03d837b351a0c105e663dcea6aee434d    3
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/time.h      f7a9165daf21d6f200ad656fbace652fcde11c4b    3
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/cdefs.h     f0704e779b9252398f7859a05cc65bbd563cdd0e    3
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/cdefs_elf.h     63e208b3b175f84e32918d08096693688d860869    3
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/time.h      f4eaf411f6b1a8817f3baed1bfbacd4ea2f51b9f    3
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/cdefs.h     f0704e779b9252398f7859a05cc65bbd563cdd0e    3
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/malloc.h        f0704e779b9252398f7859a05cc65bbd563cdd0e    3
    F:/XX/YY/ZZ/stddef.h        f0704e779b9252398f7859a05cc65bbd563cdd0e    3
--
```

The above info is in text file, and i have a perl parser
which will read the text file line by line and try to insert into database.
The object( .o) to source  (.cpp/c/h/hpp )file relationship is established in separate many to many relationship (mapping) table.

### the code summary is as below

1. read OBJECT_FILE: line, insert it with its PK, SHA1 checksum as unique.
2. fetch its PK.say PK1
3. Read 2nd line i.e OperatingSystem.cpp insert it.if error, check the error code
4. If errocode is duplicate entry, or no error -fetch its PK, say PK2

   ### 5. Insert PK1, PK2 in many to many relationship table, if error, and error code is duplicate entry - ignore it, if any other error exit.

sample code is as below

```
--
            $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO source_r_binarylist_table
                                (   Source_r_Binary_Id,
                                    Source_r_Binary_name,
                                    Source_r_Binary_FileName,
                                    Source_r_Binary_Version,
                                    FileTypeId,
                                    SourceofSource_r_Binary,
                                    Source_r_Binary_Supplier,
                                    Source_r_Binary_Originator,
                                    Source_r_Binary_Home_Page,
                                    Source_r_Binary_Download_Location,
                                    Source_r_Binary_Checksum,
                                    Source_r_Binary_Verification_Code,
                                    Excluded_Files,
                                    Source_Info,
                                    License_Concluded,
                                    LicenseIdsFromAllFiles,
                                    LicenseComments,
                                    Summary,
                                    Description,
                                    Technology_category
                                )
                                VALUES
                                    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $error_code =0;
             $sth->execute(undef,undef,$file_name,undef,$file_type,undef,undef,undef,undef,undef,$sha1_chksum,undef,undef,undef,undef,undef,undef,undef,undef,undef)
             or $error_code = $sth->err;
            #print "Error code: $error_code ; return value $DBI::state \n";

            if (($error_code != 0) && ($error_code != ERROR_CODE_DUP_ENTRY))
            {
                die "File:[".__FILE__."] Line:[".__LINE__."]:ERROR: refer DB error code, and take appropriate action".$DBI::errstr;
            }

            $sth->finish();
            #$dbh->commit or die $DBI::errstr;

            # If first time entered or same file is entered again, the checksum will remain same, hence Duplicate entry error is thrown ,its error code is 1062
            if((($error_code == 0) && ($file_type == $FILE_TYPE_OBJ)) ||(($error_code == ERROR_CODE_DUP_ENTRY) && ($file_type == $FILE_TYPE_OBJ)))
            {
                $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT Source_r_Binary_Id from source_r_binarylist_table where Source_r_Binary_Checksum = ?");
                $sth->execute( $sha1_chksum ) or die "File:[".__FILE__."] Line:[".__LINE__."]:ERROR:".$DBI::errstr;;
                while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array())
                {
                        $src_bin_id_for_obj = $row[0];
                        #print "Source Bin Id = $src_bin_id_for_obj\n";
                }
                $sth->finish();
            }

            if((($error_code == 0) || ($error_code == ERROR_CODE_DUP_ENTRY))&& 
                (($file_type == $FILE_TYPE_SRC_C) || ($file_type == $FILE_TYPE_SRC_CPP)|| 
                ($file_type == $FILE_TYPE_SRC_H) || ($file_type == $FILE_TYPE_SRC_HPP) || 
                ($file_type == $FILE_TYPE_SRC_JAVA)))
            {
                    # get the Id of newly added source (cpp or c or h or hpp or java)
                $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT Source_r_Binary_Id from source_r_binarylist_table where Source_r_Binary_Checksum = ?");
                $sth->execute( $sha1_chksum ) or die "File:[".__FILE__."] Line:[".__LINE__."]:ERROR:".$DBI::errstr;

                while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
                        $src_bin_id_for_src = $row[0];
                        #print "Source Bin Id = $src_bin_id_for_obj\n";
                }
                $sth->finish();


                $error_code_sub =0;
                #add an entry in to junction table
                $sth = $dbh->prepare(" INSERT INTO object_source_id_junctiontable (Object_Id_ref,Source_Id_ref) VALUES (?,?)");
                $sth->execute( $src_bin_id_for_obj, $src_bin_id_for_src) or  ($error_code_sub = $DBI::err);

                if (($error_code_sub != 0) && ($error_code_sub != ERROR_CODE_DUP_ENTRY))
                {
                    die "File:[".__FILE__."] Line:[".__LINE__."]:ERROR: $error_code_sub refer DB error code, and take appropriate action: ".$DBI::errstr;
                }
                $sth->finish();

                print "Line:[".__LINE__."]:Insertion successfull [Obj Id: $src_bin_id_for_obj] [Source Id: $src_bin_id_for_src]\n";
            }
    }
--
```

In above code there is huge performace issue, for insert of every line, it takes a second. Imagine if input file have around 800000 lines, then it takes around 10 days to complete the script execution.

Please guide best way to reduce the time taken to insert, if changes required in DB can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table(s).  I am especially worried about the INDEX(es) and ENGINE of the tables.  Also, how big are the tables.

*Assuming* that `Source_r_Binary_Id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you could get the id by using `LAST_INSERT_ID` or `insert_id`.  That would be a little faster than the `SELECT` you are using.  However, I see what looks like the identical `SELECT` happening again; is it?

Please boil the question down to a sequence of SQL statements; it is hard to wade through the Perl(?) code.

Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';  How much RAM do you have?

Having a `UNIQUE` key on a sha1 is deadly, but still it should not take a full second to do 2 inserts and 2 selects, each being single-row and indexed.

Ah.  If you have "indexed every column" it would take most of a second to do the `INSERT`.

Suggest you instrument the code (perhaps with Time::Hires) to see which parts are taking the longest.

(I may have more suggestions after you provide the above info.)